# Are there rules about where a long title should be broken across lines?

Tags: titles, rules

Here is the title: Clean your vessel & everything on it in a single session!

> 1. Clean your vessel
>      & everything on it
>      in a single session!
> 2. Clean your vessel &
>      everything on it in
>      a single session!

Which is correct? Both versions have lines of about the same length. How do I choose between them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about design, not language. There is no ‘correct’ here: you can break/wrap a title anywhere you want—in fact, with titles (if they’re big, main titles that are graphically styled), you can even wrap in places where normal rules of hyphenation would not allow wrapping (like wrapping the title _Inspirations_ as **INS|PIR|ATI|ONS**).

Comment: I may have inadvertently made it a design question in my edit. My purpose was to make the question about rules, rather than just "which is right" (proof-reading). If the question can be improved to move it further away from proof-reading, I'll be happy.

Comment: You should show some research into the matter. Knowing what the purpose of a title is might lead you to your answer. That might be a direction you can go with your research.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  April Fools.

Comment: Seems a perfectly valid question to me, and the first comment is indeed an answer to it. That you can linebreak a title wherever you want (if that's true) is a peculiarity of English that may not be shared by other languages.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/a/192534/338289