# Can I put a line break between "von" and "Neumann"?

Tags: typography

I'm working on a project that discusses [John von Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann). Is it okay to line-break between "von" and "Neumann," or should I specify this as a non-breaking space?

Comment: Many would say proper names are an example of a linguistic unit that should not be divided.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey could you make this an answer?

Comment: I will do that. with references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer would be to allow considerations of language and sense to outweigh those of layout and appearance. Thus 'John von Neumann' should all be on the same line.

> Setting type has changed drastically from the days of metal and
>   phototypesetting. The responsibility for composing type no longer lies
>   with a highly skilled, dedicated typographer, but more often with a
>   designer or production artist, who may not be trained in this skill.

'Breaking for sense' means not letting the software make automatic breaks, but evaluating the text, and making considered line breaks when necessary.

> When breaking for sense, strive to:
>
> Keep important phrases together
>   Avoid hyphenations
>   Break a line after punctuation
>   Pair adjectives with their nouns
>   **Keep proper names together**
>   Avoid widows
>   Group color and typestyles together

[Fine Typography: breaking for sense](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-4/fine-typography/breaking-for-sense)

Further considerations:

> Do not break up linguistic units among lines.

[..]

> When absolutely necessary to keep linguistic units together (like a
>   person’s name), then the line break should still not cause a line to
>   be more than 50% shorter than the other line.

[English line breaking rules](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67089/english-line-breaking-rules)

[How to break lines](https://translations.ted.com/How_to_break_lines)

Comment: 'Keep proper names together' is rather difficult with some Pythonesque etc contrivances. / While I consider this off-topic, I've upvoted all answers with references....

Comment: Maybe outliers make the 'rule' unwieldy, but simple cases like von Neumann or de la Billiere seem to be amenable.

Comment: Yes;  there's more of a problem with this Python character:  'When I first met Johann Gambolputty de von Ausfern-schplenden-schlitter-crasscrenbon-fried-digger-dingle-dangle-dongle-dungle-burstein-von-knacker-thrasher-apple-banger-horowitz-ticolensic-grander-knotty-spelltinkle-grandlich-grumblemeyer-spelterwasser-kurstlich-himbleeisen-bahnwagen-gutenabend-bitte-ein-nürnburger-bratwustle-gerspurten-mitz-weimache-luber-hundsfut-gumberaber-shönedanker-kalbsfleisch-mittler-aucher von Hautkopft of Ulm, he was with his wife, Sarah G...'

Comment: Does *Keep proper names together* mean don't break **John** and **von Neumann** across lines?

Comment: @vy32 - yes. Use the links I provided. This was discussed [in this link above](https://translations.ted.com/How_to_break_lines) using James Tiptree, Jr. as an example. I have edited my answer to make this clear.

Comment: Let's face it: if a name is half a line long, then refusing to break it will likely create spacing anomalies.

Comment: Note that your quote says ***strive to*** keep proper names together, which means that exceptions are allowed. In practice, you should keep *John von Neumann* all on the same line unless that results in an terrible-looking layout. If it does, then you should break between *John* and *von Neumann*. (Although what usually happens in practice is people let the software decide what to do.)

Answer (score 2):

In general, if there's a whitespace, there's reasonable grounds to consider the letters on each side to constitute separate morphemes and thus allow splitting.

Anything else is a subjective matter of type-setting and layouting.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you consider that his name is "Neumann" or "von Neumann". If he had been German then it is possible that his name would have been considered to be "Neumann". He was, however, Hungarian, and he emigrated to the USA where his name would almost certainly have been considered to be "von Neumann". You would have to check how he preferred his name to be written but I very strongly suspect that in the USA he was "von Neumann" and that therefore it would be wrong to split the "von" from the "Neumann".

My main point is that there is no general rule with names, you just have to check, if you can, how that person preferred their name to work.

Comment: But the name ***is*** German. His name when he was a Hungarian child was *Neumann János* (Hungarians put their surname first). But later, when he was a professor in Germany (1928–1933), he publshed his papers under (and undoubtedly went by) *Johann von Neumann*. When he immigrated to the U.S., he changed his first name to *John*, and became *John von Neumann*.